# Can't change the index.html file at Cordova 3.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm using `Cordova 3.5` for a project and I'm not able to change the `index.html` file. If I change that file, the `device.ready`-event is not firing.

The (standard) index.html file looks like that:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting too Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
                asfasf
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I delete the `div`s with `id` "deviceready", "event listening" or "event received" the `device.ready` event is not firing anymore.

What causes this problem?

**EDIT** The `index.js` looks like:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        alert("JO");
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? can you add your JS to the question please?

Comment: The JS is just the standard one (which comes with cordova). I know that it is not working because I just added a simple `alert("Works");` statement to the `device.ready` event. It alerts when I change nothing, and it does not alert when I delete one of the three divs I mentioned above.

Comment: Can you add your `index.js` file

Comment: @NickR i added the `index.js` to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Try commenting out the `receivedEvent` function, and the call to it: `app.receivedEvent('deviceready');`

Comment: parentElement.querySelector(id) will throw an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'querySelector' of null if you remove the deviceready div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you remove those elements, the `app.receivedEvent()` will throw an error because it's trying to manipulate elements that don't exist. This error is thrown before your `alert()` call.

Remove `app.receivedEvent('deviceready');` from `app.onDeviceReady()` and it should work.